# React native ref.current.value is not working on device

Tags: react-native, expo

I am learning React Native (sorry for this rookie question).
I am struggling to get the `TextInput` value on button click. I tried `ref.current.value` but it is returning nothing on connected devices (iOS/Android/emulator) but it is working as expected in the web.
My code looks like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState('NA');
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const handleClick = () =>{
    setVal(inputRef.current.value)
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput 
        placeholder="name..."
        ref = {inputRef}
        style={{backgroundColor: 'white', padding: 5, paddingLeft: 10, paddingBottom: 10}}
      />
      <Button 
        title="Click"
        onPress={handleClick}
      />
      <Text style={{height: 100, color: 'red', backgroundColor: 'lightblue', padding: 5}}>
        {val}
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?
Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: instead of using ref, why not using two pieces of state, one just for the input and one after button click?

Comment: Thank you for the response @HagaiHarari, could you please explain it a little bit how can I do that?

Comment: Rookie mistake...should have used useState instead of useRef and set state on onChangeText. I forgot that by default the value/state is not changed though the input value is modified. Solved.

Comment: In React, your code should work. However, in React Native it doesn't.